# Error on Project Startup relating to Entity Framework in Package Manager Console

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, entity-framework, powershell, nuget

This error has perplexed me for the last few days and can find little to no information on Google regarding this. This started the other day when I was assigned a new laptop by work and I'm essentially running this on a clean install of Windows 7 x64 with VS2012 Update 1.

Whenever I start up a project using Entity Framework 5 or 6-alpha, this exception gets thrown to the package manager console:

```
New-Object : Cannot find an overload for "Version" and the argument count: "2".
At <project path>\packages\EntityFramework.5.0.0\tools\in
it.ps1:5 char:46
+ if ($PSVersionTable.PSVersion -ge (New-Object <<<<  Version @( 3, 0 )))
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-Object], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConstructorInvokedThrowException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand

Test-ModuleManifest : Invalid Module Manifest path '<project path>
\packages\EntityFramework.5.0.0\tools\'. The path argument must resolve to a single file in the file system with a '
.psd1' extension. Please fix the path specification and try again.
At <project path>\packages\EntityFramework.5.0.0\tools\in
it.ps1:14 char:34
+ $thisModule = Test-ModuleManifest <<<<  (Join-Path $toolsPath $thisModuleManifest)
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (C:\Users\stephe...rk.5.0.0\tools\:String) [Test-ModuleManifest], InvalidOper 
   ationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_InvalidModuleManifestPath,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.TestModuleManifestCommand

Import-Module : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Name' because it is null.
At <project path>\packages\EntityFramework.5.0.0\tools\in
it.ps1:31 char:18
+     Import-Module <<<<  $thisModule
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Import-Module], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleComma 
   nd
```

I can get rid of this error by editing the package scripts manually, but that feels like it would be the wrong approach. There are also multiple instances of it checking the Powershell version in this manner so I'm suspecting it's something that's wrong with my computers's configuration.

This is affecting multiple ASP.NET MVC 4 projects of mine targeting .NET 4.5. I can't run any Entity Framework commands such as Enable-Migrations or Update-Database as a result of this error. Any clues will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got it to work, it was as simple as upgrading to PowerShell 3.0. That kinda makes the version detection pointless, but hey, at least it works.